# Is there a way to add angular to my already built rails app, without changing routes?

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

basically what the title says, I want to add angularjs to my rails app without changing my routes completely. I've been searching for a way but every article I find requires you to let angular handle the routes.

edit - I honestly just want to try ng-animate for one page mini-sites on the rails app. So if this is possible could anyone let me know?

Comment: Look at http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/09/23/writing-rails-flavored-angularjs.html and https://github.com/BrewhouseTeam/angular_sprinkles

Comment: I suppose Angularjs is meant to deal with UI rendering and it only required a browser to load just a single page, which means AngularJS would handle URL routing itself. I think keep using rails to handle URL routing is against Angular's design principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article really helped me do this: https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2013/12/11/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails

As Reborix said, Angular is a UI framework and not a backend one so routes should not be dependent on Angular. Angular is designed to be a one-page website. That being said, it is becoming more commonplace for Rails developers to have a main page, like a dashboard and use Angular on that one page.

I have an example of a simple todo app in Rails 4 that might help: https://github.com/onetwopunch/ng_todo

It is definitely NOT advisable to have a website that uses Angular on each page. That's not what it's meant for and definitely bad practice.